# Collapsible Panel Get State

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to check the state of a panel with collapsible panel extender.

I want to know on client side know whether it is expanded or collapsed.

Pretty much as simple as that. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function SomethingThatNeedsToKnowTheStateOfThePanel(){
    var extender = $find("<%= thePanelExtender.ClientID %>");
    if(extender.get_Collapsed()){
        // panel collapsed
    } else {
        // panel not collapsed
    }
}
```

Assuming that thePanelExtender is the extender control. You can also change the collapsed state using `set_Collapsed(true|false)`

See http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=230